# Clearing text in AutoCompleteTextview is NOT WORKING

Tags: android

I have a  `AutoCompleteTextview` for my FIRST app. Its function is to display the letter from the clicked `ImageButton` and by clicking an `ImageView` the text on it should be cleared to be able to put new letters. THE PROBLEM is that after clicking the `ImageView` the letters/words that has been cleared will display again and the newly clicked letter serves as adddition to the previous word(s).

Example:
I first created the word "WORD" using the `ImageButtons` then I clicked the `ImageView` to clear the `AutoCompleteTexView` and when I click any `ImageButton` like for example I clicked letter A, the `AutoCompleteTextView` would display "WORDA".

**These is the code I use for displaying the letters.**

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Log.i(TAG,"arg0.getId() = " + arg0.getId());

                if (arg0.getId()==R.drawable.a){
                    Log.i(TAG,"arg0.getId()="+arg0.getId());
                    generatedString=generatedString+"a";
                    text.setText(generatedString);
                    ((ImageButton) arg0).setImageResource(R.drawable.changea);

                        if (!timeHasStarted) {
                               countDownTimer.start();
                               timeHasStarted = true;
                               }
```

**For clearing the word.**

```
            text.setText("");
```

Comment: `generatedString=generatedString+"a";`. I bet you never clear `generatedString`.

Comment: Yes, that´s it, make generatedString empty like njzk2 said, for example generatedString="";

Comment: I didn't. I'll try it.

Comment: It worked! I have another question, how can i eliminate the blank space created in the autocompletetexview whenever I click my first button?(after launching it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearing the textView like this:

```
text.setText("");
generatedString = "";
```

Comment: It worked! I have another question, how can i eliminate the blank space created in the autocompletetexview whenever I click my first button?(after launching it). Ex.: WORD it creates a space before W like _WORD